# How can I block user interactions with the background views while modal transitions popup shows in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to block tapping views in background of my modal transition popup. How can I achieve this in swiftUI? (my example modal transition https://youtube.com/shorts/9GT1xNlzCiE?feature=share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.disabled(Bool)` in your background view with a @State Boolean variable. As-

```
struct HomePageSwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var isModalShowing: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
            VStack() {
                // Your background view
            }
            .disabled(isModalShowing)
            VStack() {
               // Your background view
            }
            .disabled(isModalShowing)
            VStack() {
               // Your popup view (Dont add it)
            }
    }
}
```

While clicking alert button just set `isModalShowing = true` and also `isModalShowing = false` when alert dismissed.

Comment: disabled(isModalShowing) also disabled modal popup views

Comment: Did you add `.disabled(isModalShowing)` in popup view? You should use it only where you need to disable. Not in whole view. Add `.disabled(isModalShowing)` for all view that you need to disable.